# Echo var before insert to database

Tags: php

Is it possible to show variable username before I am putting it into DB? Echo, alert, console or something? I want to check what is in $username before do INSERT

```
 <?php

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->username);


    $query = "INSERT into tablename (username) VALUES ('$username')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    echo true;
    ?>
```

Comment: `echo $username;` ?

Comment: Why would it _not_ be possible? You seem to know about PHP's `echo` and JavaScript's `alert()` and `console.log()` already, and `$username` is just a variable…

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into the SQL.

Comment: Do you want to see username first and then decide whether  put into DB or not ?

Comment: I am taking username from input field and I want to show what user inputed.

Comment: @David doesn't work...

Comment: @Defus: Define "doesn't work".  `echo $username;` will, in fact, echo whatever is in the `$username` variable.  If you're doing something else wrong, you're going to have to explain it.  And whether this is done "before" or "after" the query really makes no difference here, since both of those things are in the same operation.

Comment: Everything works fine I can insert into database. I just want to show what is inside before INSERT

Comment: @Defus: It's not clear at all what you're asking or what isn't working here.  Nor is it even clear why you need to return data to the client that you *just received from the client*, since clearly the client *already has* that data.  At the very least, it sounds like you're confused about the difference between client-side and server-side code here.  If that's the case, this would be a good place for you to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: @David ok from the beginning I am using angular where I am getting current Date. But when I inserting it into database I have mytime - 1 hrs. For example is 14:55 so I get 13:55.
In my code I do {{myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss'}} for check variable myDate and also works fine but in a while I tried insert it into database I am getting correct date and incorret time.
So I want to show variable before Insert it just for test. 
There is $username just for example

Comment: @Defus: And what happens when you simply do `echo $username;`?  I don't know what client-side functionality you expect to be performed, because the question contains nothing about that.  But anything you `echo` will be in the HTTP response.  Echo the username, echo the SQL query, echo anything you like.  It will be in the response.  If it's "not working" (whatever that means), then what are you doing with the response?  Are you looking at it at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136160/discussion-between-defus-and-david).

Comment: @David I moved discussion to chat

Comment: @Defus: Sorry, I don't offer private tutoring services.  If you have information relevant to the question, it should be put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->username);

 if($username)
 {
  echo $username;

$query = "INSERT into tablename (username) VALUES ('$username')";

mysqli_query($connect, $query);


}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->username);


    $query = "INSERT into tablename (username) VALUES ('$username')";


    echo "<script>alert('".$username."')</script>";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    echo true;
    ?>
```

Comment: echo $username ;
if this prints username, then It must give alert box written username.

Comment: Check if your browser has JavaScript enabled. Still you can try this 

echo "<script>console.log('".$a."')</script>";

Comment: ofc is enabled but still nothing. hmm

Comment: Code only answers are considered "bad form". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I can't show here even Hello World alert. There is my angular piece http://pastebin.com/V67KDLuS

Comment: @Defus: According to that "angular piece" you're not *trying* to show any kind of alert.  The response from the server is in the `data` variable in the AJAX callback, a variable you're not using for anything.

Comment: @David I am using to insert it into database I don't want it for something else

Comment: @Defus: If you don't want to do *anything else* other than insert into the database, and if it is *currently* inserting into the database, then *what are you even asking here*?  That last comment contradicts everything you've asked/said so far in this question.  Nobody can help you if you can't even decide what you're trying to do.